# Написать регулярное выражение с хитрым условием

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужна регулярка, которая бы проверяла ссылку с такими условиями:

- ссылка относительная
- ссылка может содержать что угодно (пусть будет так, в смысле любые символы)
- ссылка может содержать слово after (в любой позиции), только в том случае если это before/after

Вот что у меня получилось. Условие с http(s) и after отрабатывает нормально, то есть after работает только после before. Но ничего другое не отрабатывает, ну например просто '/foo/bar'

```js
/^(?<!https?:\/\/).*(?<=before\/)after/.test('/before/after')
```

Comment: Если на пальцах, то 2 последних пункта можно объединить в "before/after или не after"

Comment: Может, `/^(?!https?:\/\/)(?!.*(?<!before\/)after).*/`?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/w5kUAt/2/?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew благодарю. Ответ добавьте чтоб можно было принять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
/^(?!https?:\/\/)(?!.*(?<!before\/)after).*/
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/w5kUAt/2/)

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?!https?:\/\/)` - в начале не должно быть `https://` или `http://`
- `(?!.*(?<!before\/)after)` - в строке не должно быть `after`, перед которым нет `before/`
- `.*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от символов перехода на новую строку, как можно больше